# Python Socket Programming Simple Web Server

Tags: python, sockets, web, websocket

I am working on my first Python socket programming code and I cannot figure out what is wrong.  I type in the IP address of the server that this program is running on along with the port number and the file I am trying to receive.  I should receive the file in the browser and the socket should close.  Instead, the server prints out the print line 'Ready to serve...' three times, displays '404 Not Found' on the browser, and never closes the socket.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#import socket module
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
#Prepare a sever socket
serverSocket.bind(('', 12006))
serverSocket.listen(1)
while True:
    print 'Ready to serve...'
    #Establish the connection
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        f.close()
        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found')
        #Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: How do you know it never closes the socket?

Comment: Try printing the IOError exception object, that might give more info.  You could be getting the IOError from the file open.  Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I have tried it in python 2.7.5 and Windows Vista and it works.

Comment: @rafalopez79 I am using python 2.7.9.  Where should the file I am accessing be located?  Maybe this is my problem.

Comment: I am testing it with: http://127.0.0.1:12006/test.py where test.py is yout python script

Comment: @sweeneyrod Because I can't run the same code twice.  It says that the port is currently in use.  Also, the python GUI that I am running the code in shows me that it is still running.  If the socket closed the program would exit

Comment: @rafalopez79  I am using the python GUI to run the python server script and the file I want to access is a separate html file.  I was asking where that html file should be in order for me to access it.

Comment: add this: import os  \n  print os.getcwd() to the begining of your script, this is the base folder for your web server

Comment: The HTML file should be in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for all the help.  I figured out what was wrong.  I had renamed my HTML to "HelloWorld.html" and then Windows automatically added .html to end of the file.  So in order to have accessed the file I would of needed to type in HelloWorld.html.html.  I changed the file name and then this code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
# python 3
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5500))
serverSocket.listen(1)
while True:
    print("Server is running")
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1].decode('utf-8').strip("/")
        print(filename)
        f = open(filename)
        outputdata = f.read()
        f.close()
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n'.encode())
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found'.encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

Before this line   `filename = message.split()[1]`

```
print(message)
```

after this line   `filename = message.split()[1]`

```
print(filename)
```

I thought that the error is in that line.